# Difference between W3C standard and W3C recommendation?

Tags: w3c

Does anyone know, whats the difference between a W3C recommendation and a W3C standard?

Is there a difference? Or is it just two ways of saying the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard usually something that is legally enforceable. W3C does not publish standards. "W3C develops technical specifications and guidelines through a process designed to maximize consensus about the content of a technical report, to ensure high technical and editorial quality, and to earn endorsement by W3C and the broader community." (from [here](http://www.w3.org/standards/)). Such specifications are called W3C recommendations.

You will find a very lively debate on the use of these terms [here](http://www.w3.org/QA/2009/05/_watching_the_google_io.html).

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_recommendation:
"A W3C Recommendation is the final stage of a ratification process of the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) working group concerning a standard."